# How to raise the height of a hat when it is over just an empty space?

Tags: symbols

I would like to write a hat over just an empty space, like `\hat{ }`. My problem is that I need it to be at a certain height, which happens to be higher that the standard height I get with the previous command. I tried to raise the hat using `\vspace{}` like this: `\hat{\vspace{.1cm}}` (changing the `.1cm` to different values), but got no result; the hat remains at the same height. So I would like to know of an alternative way of doing what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Here I put `\hat` over a hard space, otherwise it takes up no width.  Then, I can use `\raisebox` to lift it higher.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a \hat{~} b \raisebox{2pt}{$\hat{~}$} c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To obey the smaller mathstyles, I make the macro `\highhat[]` that can take a real number as an optional argument, specifying the number of "local-mathstyle points" to raise the hat (default `2\LMpt`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\highhat[1][2]{\ThisStyle{\raisebox{#1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\hat{~}$}}}
\begin{document}
$a \hat{~} b \highhat c \highhat[4] d$

$\scriptstyle a \hat{~} b \highhat c \highhat[4] d$

$\scriptscriptstyle a \hat{~} b \highhat c \highhat[4] d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option that might help you is to place the hat over a `phantom` character.  The `phantom` character will not be shown, but still takes up space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\hat{~} \hat{b} \hat{\phantom{b}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]